# Mongo DB Authentication doesn't work with security.authorization enabled

Tags: mongodb

I am using a fresh Mongo DB 3.4 install and have created a user in the admin database.

When I attempt to connect to the database without `security.authorization` enabled, I can do so with or without specifying the user account.

```
mongo
```

or

```
mongo -u "username" -p "password"
```

Now, if I change the value of `security.authorization` in the `mongod.conf` file, it no longer allows me to connect - even if I specify the username and password as above.

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

The user account has been added to the `admin` database and is given the `userAdminAnyDatabase` role applied to it.

The error message is as follows when I attempt to connect:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
2017-01-04T23:43:39.078+0000 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-01-04T23:43:39.078+0000 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I have figured this out. For some reason after enabling `security.authorization`, I needed to start the `mongodb` service rather than the `mongod` service.